# Values in shiny widget are not displayed after using as input subseted data,

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create two widgets where the first one will subset the second but both of them do not seem to work properly as I see no selected values.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinyWidgets)
x1<-data.frame(
  structure(list(`REGION NAME` = c("Central", "Multinational", 
                                   "East", "South", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "Multinational", 
                                   "Multinational", "Multinational", "West", "East", "South", "South", 
                                   "East", "East", "North", "Multinational"), `Sector Complex Name` = c("AHVP", 
                                                                                                        "PEVP", "PEVP", "PIVP", "AHVP", "AHVP", "AHVP", "AHVP", "PIVP", 
                                                                                                        "PIVP", "PIVP", "PIVP", "AHVP", "AHVP", "PIVP", "AHVP", "AHVP", 
                                                                                                        "AHVP", "PEVP", "PIVP")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                     "tbl", "data.frame"))
)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
   
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Lending Approvals",
               fluidRow(
                 column(2,
                        
                        pickerInput(
                          inputId = "reg",
                          label = "Select region",
                          choices = unique(x1$`REGION NAME`),
                          selected=unique(x1$`REGION NAME`[1]),
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          options = list(
                            `actions-box` = TRUE,
                            `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                            `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                          )
                        )
                 ),
                 column(2,
                        uiOutput("sector")
                        
                 )
               ),
               
      )
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  subsets1<-reactive({
    d<-subset(x1,`REGION NAME` %in% input$reg)
    d<-data.frame(d)
  })
  output$sector<-renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "sec",
      label = "Select sectors",
      choices = unique(subsets1()$`Sector Complex Name`),
      selected=unique(subsets1()$`Sector Complex Name`[1]),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = list(
        `actions-box` = TRUE,
        `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
        `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
        `none-selected-text` = "zero"
      )
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamically rendering the entire `pickerInput` using the `renderUI` function, it's easier to dynamically update the picker select options instead.

You can see in the following code that I have placed the `pickerInput` in the UI to begin with and simply set the choices to NULL. Then, on observing a change in the first `pickerInput`, the second `pickerInput` is updated dynamically using `updatePickerInput`.

I also added `session` to the server function. This is important when using the update function.

```r
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title="Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
        titleWidth = 400
        
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabsetPanel(
            
            tabPanel("Lending Approvals",
                     fluidRow(
                         column(2,
                                
                                pickerInput(
                                    inputId = "reg",
                                    label = "Select region",
                                    choices = unique(x1$`REGION NAME`),
                                    selected=unique(x1$`REGION NAME`[1]),
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    options = list(
                                        `actions-box` = TRUE,
                                        `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                        `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                                        `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                                    )
                                )
                         ),
                         column(2,
                                pickerInput(
                                    inputId = "sec",
                                    label = "Select sectors",
                                    choices = NULL,
                                    selected= NULL,
                                    multiple = TRUE,
                                    options = list(
                                        `actions-box` = TRUE,
                                        `deselect-all-text` = "None...",
                                        `select-all-text` = "Yeah, all !",
                                        `none-selected-text` = "zero"
                                    )
                                )
                                
                         )
                     ),
                     
            )
            
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    shiny::observeEvent(input$reg, {
        new_choices <- unique(
            subset(x1,`REGION NAME` %in% input$reg)$`Sector Complex Name`
        )
        shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = "sec",
            choices = new_choices,
            selected = new_choices[1]
        )
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```